# How to change external port forwarding for an application?

Tags: networking, port-forwarding

[image: GTA Online network settings]One of the application in my windows pc has the external port assigned to it as Port 0 and hence i am not able to connect to online server through it. I have talked to the manufacturer of the app regarding but to no vail. I tried reinstalling the application, but it is assigning Itself port 0 for as the external port.

Can anyone suggest me a way so that I can change the external port .
Thank you

Comment: You should probably phrase this better. Port 0 is not a valid port in UDP nor TCP (if you request port 0 the OS will assign an arbitrary port that is available)

Comment: Yes agreed, but the OS ain't assigning it